# too many file handles open .net Core 3.1 on docker AWS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

we recently tried to migrate an .net core app to aws ecs . but we had a lot of issues, after a while, the container stopped because the tcp stack was full. We've upgraded our way of performing requsts, with HttpClientFactory, we tried a lot of alternatives , but wihout any success. What we've noticed, is that on the containers we have a lot of file handles in use. When a container dies, it has about 150k file handles.
It looks like every single thread that has been spawned (per httpRequest for example) is loading in memory  all the current libraries requied by the application.

and it looks something like this:

```
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               402514 /app/pt-BR/Ubisoft.Connect2.Services.Lib.resources.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               402510 /app/nl/Ubisoft.Connect2.Services.Lib.resources.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267308 /app/Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267304 /app/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267473 /app/cs/Ubisoft.Connect2.Services.Lib.resources.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               131880 /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.8/mscorlib.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267444 /app/System.Web.Http.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267248 /app/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267255 /app/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267381 /app/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Contracts.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267385 /app/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267410 /app/StackExchange.Redis.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267257 /app/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               402535 /app/runtimes/linux-x64/native/libuv.so (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267286 /app/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267350 /app/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267436 /app/System.ServiceModel.Http.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267346 /app/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Composite.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267302 /app/Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267264 /app/Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1              1840740 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.2 (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               131831 /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.8/System.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl.so (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267429 /app/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               402550 /app/runtimes/unix/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267377 /app/Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267311 /app/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267276 /app/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267284 /app/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267313 /app/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267244 /app/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267242 /app/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
dotnet    22035           root  mem       REG              259,1               267369 /app/Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.dll (stat: No such file or directory)
```

and the file names are repeating thousand of times, on and on.
Not to mention that there are a lot of No such file or directory.

We are kinda running out of options, and on windows with IIS + Kestrel we didn't had this kind of issue. Every thing worked perfectly, but we decided that we want AWS :)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: this log is from when we had the app on .net 2.2, we`ve upgraded it to 3.1

Comment: How is the file handeling implemented? Are you mapping files to the container(s)? Because the logs are screaming `No such file or directory`

Comment: I have a ton of questions. You have some output.. where is that output coming from? You said that the log is from 2.2... well, can you show us the log from 3.1? All threads of a process share file handles...why are you worried about it? Can you reproduce the issue in a smaller context? Does a binary chop (remove half the features/half the code) show a change? Can you reproduce it in a small program that uses `HttpClientFactory` directly? Can you take a look at all the file handles that are open, then remove the ones that correspond to the .NET Core libraries themselves? Post that, maybe?

Comment: so this happens only with higher loads, like +20k requests per minute. with lower loads, everyting works fine. we are not doing anything with the files, those are standard .net core app files. i dont know why there are so many not found errors. For 3.1 it looks exactly the same. right now we are trying to make everything async/await